# localizable.strings adding new strings

Tags: iphone, localization, nslocalizedstring

When localizing my apps I use  `genstrings -o en.lproj *.m` to create the initial Localizable.strings file and translate it. So far so good.

The problem arises when the app changes and some of the former NSLocalizableStrings change, get deleted or new ones are added. When using `genstrings -o en.lproj *.m` again, it overwrites the translated file and I either have to copy from a backup, manually check which entries changed, and then translate the new ones + deleting the unused ones.

Is there a better way to merge the changes into the translated Localizable.strings file? The way I am doing it is quite error prone to changes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made good experience with [The Localization Suite](http://www.loc-suite.org/) You can scan (and Rescan) the classes, build a database of the translations and recycle already translated strings.

Comment: tried it, only managed to work with .strings and xib. can it help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740518/use-genstrings-with-a-folder-structured-project-for-localization