# Use genstrings with a folder-structured project for localization

Tags: xcode, localization, genstrings

In an iOS Project with folders containing *.m files, similar to packages, one will have to run
`genstrings -o en.lproj *.m` for each folder and match the relative en.lproj path. Is there a command that will do the drill down from the root folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate all of the *.m files into one file and then call the *genstrings* on that.

I.E:

```
find . -name "*.m" -exec cat {} >> all.txt \;
```

Comment: i have created file with your instructions but unable to use genstrings command on that. can you please elaborate the line to deal with txt file ?

Answer (score 2):

In Greenwich we use `find` piped to `xargs`. You can see how that's done [here](https://github.com/fadingred/Greenwich/blob/master/Framework/Scripts/actions/create), but it's basically:

```
find "path/to/directory" -name "*.m" -print0 |
  xargs -0 genstrings -s NSLocalizedString -o "path/to/output.strings"
```

I'd also recommend taking a look at [Greenwich](https://github.com/fadingred/Greenwich) as it makes the whole process of localization much easier.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a simple folder struct you probably get away with a simple

```
genstrings -ao <destination> <root>/*/*.m
```

using one `*` for each level of subfolder.

Alternatively and if the folders have different nesting levels you are better off using:

```
  find <root>/* -iname "*.m"  -type f -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -ao <destination>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this line just solved all problems. You even don't need to copy all m-Files to one document, before running the line in the shell. Just step into your project folder and run it, and all even the subfolders will be checked:

```
find . -name \*.m | xargs genstrings -o "directory/"
```

just create the directory before running it, otherwise you get an exception.

Comment: Works with Xcode11, iOS13, swift: find . -name \*.swift | xargs genstrings -o "directory/"